# HTML - TD border not showing in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following css class:

```
.detail tr td
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0 ;
}
```

And it works great in firefox, chrome and IE9.

But IE7 draws a border in the bottom of all the `td` that have text. But if the `td` doesn't have text, then it doesn't draw the border.

How can I add the border for all of them in IE7?

Comment: Try adding &nbsp; to empty cells.

Comment: any chance of seeing the html?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In IE7, empty tables cells don't exist. Adding a `&nbsp;` to the all your empty cells will solve your issue.

**Additional Information:**

If you're using jQuery, you could add the `&nbsp;` dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td:empty").html("&nbsp;");
});
```

If you hate the idea of inserting a `&nbsp;`, you could add a span and set one of it's properties:

```
<span style="zoom:1;"></span>
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td:empty").html("<span style='zoom:1;'></span>");
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but above jquery function doesn't working

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani, If you're talking about the `<span>` solution, it's because I didn't fix my nested quotes when I copied & pasted. I've updated the answer

Comment: @ghanshyam.mirani do you have your jQuery version linked in your page?